# Google Sheet script - Automatically send an email with values when they are added to a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been trying to follow the document below but have got a bit stuck. In short, I am trying to have a Google Sheet send out an email automatically when two values are added to a Google Sheet (Name, Telephone)

The function below works great when I run it from App script but I am looking for it to grab the values that are inserted at the time and send the email automatically rather than having to run the script each time in App Script.

```
// Fetch the email address
var emailRange = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'This is your Alert email!'; // Second column
var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/google-sheets-send-email-based-on-cell-value/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the onEdit feature.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

```
function onEdit(e){
  sendEmailToUpdatedValue(e)
}
function sendEmailToUpdatedValue(e){
  let email_x = /\b[\w\.\-\+]+@[\w\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,13}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,13}|\b)/;
  let email = e.range.getValue();
  let is_email = email_x.test(email);
  if(is_email){
    //your email function here
  }
}
```

Be sure to run the onEdit function once within Apps Script in order to ensure the trigger is set up. That first time will get an error.

Keep in mind that onEdit only fires from a user action, so if the emails are being added from a form or some other script, this will not work. In those scenarios you would need a time based trigger.